# O(n^3) is a running time

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I have this true or false question O(n^3) is a running time or a function which gives the running time of algorithm

I know the answer is false but I want to know if I want to correct the mistake what is the correct statement will be

Comment: [Big-O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) is really about *complexity*. This should have been taught by your books or classes.

Comment: I think your question is better fit for [cs.stackexchange.com](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: O(n^3) is a **set** of functions that grow at most as fast as n^3 asymptotically (this has a formal definition that you can try to study). This set can be used to describe the *time complexity* of an algorithm, which can say something about how its running time changes as a function of the input, but does not say anything about the running time in itself. It can also be used for other things.

Answer (score 0):

A running time should be in time units. Since I see no time units, that is not a time. Likewise for a function that gives a running time. Also, while most big-oh notation refers to (worst/average-)time, you can also use it to specify (worst/average-)space - and this should be clearly specified in the problem.

In Big-Oh notation, you are not dealing with values or functions, but rather with whole **classes** of functions. O(n³) worst-time complexity is the **complexity class** of algorithms where the longest time they can require to return a result grows by no-less than the size of their input to the 3rd power, discarding any constant multiplicative factors.